# Sending JSONObject to Flask API from my App

Tags: java, android, json, api, flask

So i've been trying to send a JSONObject containing a base64 encoded image to an API i made with Flask and is being hosted on a test webserver.

```
            String imgData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            try{
                jsonObj.put("imgurl", imgData);

                sendPost(jsonObj);
                }
            catch (JSONException e){
                Context context2 = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text2 = "Bye toast!";
                int duration2 = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context2, text2, duration2);
                toast2.show();
            }
            try {
                Context connTe = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence connectText = "Connection function successful";
                int connectDur = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast connectToast = Toast.makeText(connTe, connectText, connectDur);
                connectToast.show();

                URL url = new URL("http://BLABLABLA.pythonanywhere.com/image");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                Log.i("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                os.writeBytes(jsonObj.toString());

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

                conn.disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception a) {
                a.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But when i look in the logs, there isn't even any activity. The api works correctly as i tested it with Postman multiple times.

What am i missing?

Edit:
The toasts in there are just for me randomly wanting to see some function related stuff, will be removed.

> !11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
>   11-07 12:26:24.665 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCaptureActivity$3.onPictureTaken(BarcodeCaptureActivity.java:402)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSource$PictureDoneCallback.onPictureTaken(CameraSource.java:697)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1611)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
>   11-07 12:26:24.666 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   11-07 12:26:24.667 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
>   11-07 12:26:24.667 6228-6228/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)>!

**EDIT**

For those of you who run into the same problem, it had to do with internet premissions i forgot to give my application.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I added the trace, because i'm not sure.

Comment: You are performing this in Background thread?.As it shows NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: Yes it's asynchronous

Comment: Ah. with your help i actually fixed the error. Thank you !